# Selecting a range in an if-statement (Excel2010/VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out VBA and Excel and I've ran into some problems. I'm trying to select a range, and depending on if another column(P) is empty, I'll choose either column N or M to select.

Basically I've tried something like this without success.

```
IF(P7="",Range("N7").Select , Range("M7").Select)
```

So in pseudo code:

> IF P7 is empty DO N7.Select ELSE M7.Select

I Appreciate any help, since I can't find anything about this!

-P

Comment: Kindly 'close' the questions by marking correct answers. This is what people here like when helping others. It will help ppl with same problem to identify the correct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the IF statement is different between the Excel function and the VBA code

```
Sub MySelect()

If Range("P7") = "" Then
   Range("N7").Select
 Else
   Range("M7").Select
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Select case Statement can be done as below.
 [**Select should be avoided**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179)

```
retVal = Range("P7").Value
    Select Case retVal
    Case Is = vbNullString
        Range("N7").Select
    Case Else
        Range("M7").Select
    End Select
```